# Deleting from and writing to SQLite, using JSON data to sync remote tables in MySQL

Tags: iphone, mysql, ios, json, sqlite

First of all, I have been reading many questions that seem similar to mine, and even took some advise from several in order to reach the point where I am, so I thank you stackoverflow users.

Ok, I have five database tables total in SQLite for the iOS side of the App, and their equivalent in MySQL for the remote server. The data I preloaded the SQLite tables with displays fine and the App functions as expected. The problem arises when I download the JSON data from the remote database in order to replace the local information stored in the iOS device. I will keep it simple by referring to a single table:

```
    // Create an object, reading its information from the local database.
    Pregunta *objPregunta = [[Pregunta alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:0 database:delegate.database];
    // Erase all data in the object's table (preguntas) see method below.
    [objPregunta deleteAllFromDatabase];
    // Obtain the remote objects retrieved via JSON, and cycle them.
    NSArray *preguntas = (NSArray *)[responseDict objectForKey:@"preguntas"];
    for (id pregunta in preguntas) {
        // Create a dictionary storing the JSON object.
        NSDictionary *pregunta_dict = (NSDictionary *) pregunta;

        // Send the dictionary to the function for SQLite insertion.
        [objPregunta insertNewRecordIntoDatabase:pregunta_dict];
    }
    // Free the object resources.
    [objPregunta release];
```

This is the SQLite deletion function associated to the Pregunta object in the code above:

```
- (void) deleteAllFromDatabase {
    if(delete_statement == nil) {
        const char *sql = "DELETE FROM preguntas";

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &delete_statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error: Failed to prepare SQL statement: %s.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }
    }

    if (sqlite3_step(delete_statement) != SQLITE_DONE) {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to save priority with message: %s.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }

    sqlite3_reset(delete_statement);
}
```

And finally, this is the function that inserts the new record into the database, using the dictionary object passed to it:

```
- (void) insertNewRecordIntoDatabase:(NSDictionary *)pregunta_dict {
    if (insert_statement == nil) {
        const char *sql = "INSERT INTO preguntas (id_forma, numero, seccion, texto, respuesta, comentario, requiere_fotografia, fotografia, tipo) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

        self.id_forma            = [[pregunta_dict objectForKey:@"id_forma"] integerValue];
        self.numero              = [[pregunta_dict objectForKey:@"numero"]   integerValue];
       if([pregunta_dict objectForKey:@"seccion"] == [NSNull null]) {
            self.seccion         = nil;
        } else {
            self.seccion         = [pregunta_dict  objectForKey:@"seccion"];
        }
        self.texto               = [pregunta_dict  objectForKey:@"texto"];
        if([pregunta_dict objectForKey:@"respuesta"] == [NSNull null]) {
            self.respuesta       = nil;
        } else {
            self.respuesta       = [pregunta_dict  objectForKey:@"respuesta"];
        }
        if([pregunta_dict objectForKey:@"comentario"] == [NSNull null]) {
            self.comentario      = nil;
        } else {
            self.comentario      = [pregunta_dict  objectForKey:@"comentario"];
        }
        self.requiere_fotografia = [pregunta_dict  objectForKey:@"requiere_fotografia"];
        if([pregunta_dict objectForKey:@"fotografia"] == [NSNull null]) {
            self.fotografia      = nil;
        } else {
            self.fotografia      = [pregunta_dict  objectForKey:@"fotografia"];
        }
        self.tipo                = [pregunta_dict  objectForKey:@"tipo"];

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &insert_statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error: Failed to prepare SQL statement: %s.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        } else {
            @try {
                sqlite3_bind_int (insert_statement, 1, self.id_forma);
                sqlite3_bind_int (insert_statement, 2, self.numero);
                sqlite3_bind_text(insert_statement, 3, [self.seccion             UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                sqlite3_bind_text(insert_statement, 4, [self.texto               UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                sqlite3_bind_text(insert_statement, 5, [self.respuesta           UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                sqlite3_bind_text(insert_statement, 6, [self.comentario          UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                sqlite3_bind_text(insert_statement, 7, [self.requiere_fotografia UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                sqlite3_bind_text(insert_statement, 8, [self.fotografia          UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                sqlite3_bind_text(insert_statement, 9, [self.tipo                UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            }
            @catch (NSException *exception) {
                ;
            }
        }
    }

    if (sqlite3_step(insert_statement) != SQLITE_DONE) {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to prepare SQL statement: %s.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    } else {
    NSLog(@"Pregunta insert_id: %lld", sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database));
    }

    sqlite3_reset(insert_statement);
}
```

Now, the problem with the code is that somehow it seems to be inserting the rows incorrectly, because when the delete/insert processes complete for all of the tables and I read the data inserted from SQLite I end up having duplicated values in the database.

I thought it had something to do with the `deleteAllFromDatabase` function, but then again it seems too straightforward as to be causing any trouble. I also tried to directly specify which values I want stored for the primary keys, but the App crashes with because apparently a constraint is not met (I've no foreign keys, just a primary key on each table).

What suggestions do you guys have? Please ignore the empty catch blocks, I've tested them and removed their code so I could make things shorter here in the source I publish for you. Also, the statements are local static variables for the class that I reuse and reset as needed.

Thanks for any input you may provide. I will be posting back any further details you may need from me to disclose in order to better understand what I am doing.

---

*Here's some findings I've managed to catch:*

- Since I am displaying the rows in a TableView, I can see that all of
  the values in the database table are exactly the same (I also
  NSLogged them), except for the primary key (which is autogenerated by
  SQLite INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT)... so that probably means there's
  something wrong with my insert statements, or the way I send the
  dictionary data for each of the rows to be inserted.
- As far as the data in the JSON resource there is no problems at all
  with it, I have captured the whole string, indented it, and displayed
  it to verify complete integrity of the information and it all matches
  that of the remote MySQL tables.
- In the first block of code, the foreach loop reads: `for (id pregunta in preguntas) {` however in [this article](http://www.xprogress.com/post-44-how-to-parse-json-files-on-iphone-in-objective-c-into-nsarray-and-nsdictionary/) you will find they are using `for (id *item in items) {` instead (with the * as in for a pointer). I've tried to make it similar but I get an error and the code will not compile no matter what.
- Is there a chance that I would need to somehow *reset* the `DSDictionary` that I pass to the `insertNewRecordIntoDatabase:` function so it will not contain previous values? I would assume that for each iteration the data would be different, but this is proving me wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally solved the problem. The class' static `insert_statement` variable (from  `sqlite3_stmt`) was causing the problem, because when I deleted them from the class declaration and instead created/finalized them within the `- (void) insertNewRecordIntoDatabase:(NSDictionary *)pregunta_dict` function then all the inserts worked perfectly. I have no duplicate rows now in the local SQLite database.

So, lesson learned: at least for the `INSERT` statements make sure you use new `sqlite3_stmt` objects and `sqlite3_finalize()` them, instead of recycling them via `sqlite3_reset()` like I was doing, otherwise you might end up with the statement inserting the same data on subsequent calls.

I also made a few changes to the overall class' insert function, as I now pass it an object of the class' very same type as parameter, and access its properties for column matching at the time of the insertion. Here's my final code:

```
- (void) insertInstanceIntoDatabase: (Pregunta *)pregunta database: (sqlite3 *)db {
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt_insert = nil;
    const char *sql = "INSERT INTO preguntas (id_pregunta, id_forma, numero, seccion, texto, respuesta, comentario, requiere_fotografia, fotografia, tipo) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &stmt_insert, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error: Failed to prepare SQL statement: %s.", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    } else {
        @try {
            sqlite3_bind_int (stmt_insert, 1,  pregunta.id_pregunta);
            sqlite3_bind_int (stmt_insert, 2,  pregunta.id_forma);
            sqlite3_bind_int (stmt_insert, 3,  pregunta.numero);
            sqlite3_bind_text(stmt_insert, 4, [pregunta.seccion             UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(stmt_insert, 5, [pregunta.texto               UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(stmt_insert, 6, [pregunta.respuesta           UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(stmt_insert, 7, [pregunta.comentario          UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(stmt_insert, 8, [pregunta.requiere_fotografia UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(stmt_insert, 9, [pregunta.fotografia          UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(stmt_insert,10, [pregunta.tipo                UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception) {
            ;
        }
    }

    if (sqlite3_step(stmt_insert) != SQLITE_DONE) {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to prepare SQL statement: %s.", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(stmt_insert);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are possible explanations for the duplicates. Check these first:

1. You are not reading and displaying the records correctly.
2. When you insert the records, you are inserting twice.

   - (Maybe the function that does the insertion gets called more than once.)
3. The MySQL database on the server has duplicates.
4. You have not deleted the original records.

   - (I guess you ruled that one out.)

Hope this helps. Cheers,
Sascha

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Mundi, I've updated my question to reflect further findings.

Comment: - Maybe the primary key can help you. Are the primary keys of two identical records adjacent or not?

Comment: The table structure is set to add the primary keys automagically, as the columns are INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, I don't even set the primary key's column/value when inserting new records... their insertion is managed by sqlite.